# Interface pattern for constants class

Tags: java, spring, oop, design-patterns

I am working on an application that has to read certain data from the screen, and to do so I am using a constants class to specify the position of the data in the screen. For instance, one variable with information would look like this:

```
//Square of 100x15 px containing the name of the current user
public static final int[] USERNAME = {1157, 700, 100, 15};
//Squares for the five 16x23 numbers common to all players 
private static final int[][] COMMON_NUMBERS = {
            {426, 230, 16, 23},
            {514, 230, 16, 23},
            {601, 230, 16, 23},
            {688, 230, 16, 23},
            {775, 230, 16, 23}};
```

An example of the use of this class would be:

```
BufferedImage username = screenshot.getSubimage(Constants.USERNAME[0], Constants.USERNAME[1], Constants.USERNAME[2], Constants.USERNAME[3]);
```

Up to here everything is fine, but now I need more Constants representing the same thing but for a different screen resolution. I cannot multiply by the ratio of the screen resolutions, as some element's positions are slightly different and sometimes the readings aren't correct.
I was wondering whether there was a nice and clean design pattern for this situation that I can use, as I am not fully convinced with the different options that I have in mind:

- Adding resolution as a new dimension of the variables, for instance the above example would be something like this:

> public static final int[][] USERNAME = {{1157, 700, 100, 15},{1100,
>   650, 100, 15}};

and I will need to send information about which resolution it is from every class using these constants. Also, when adding a few more different resolutions this class would become extremely big.

- Using an interface containing getters for all attributes, for instance:

> int[] getUsername();
>   int[][] getCommonNumbers();

Then, for each resolution I would implement this interface, and I would set the correct implementation with spring whenever my application starts.

- Using an intermediate class instead of an interface, which will contain information about the resolution to use, will contain all methods as the previous interface, and will return the attribute from the correct constants file. This could be done implementing manually all methods or with java reflections, so that one central method could handle all calls. This way whenever I want to use my constants I would call the intermediate class.

I wanted to know what would be a good design for this problem, as I am not fully convinced with any of these solutions. Is there some design pattern for this?
I was reading about the Constant interface, but I am not sure about how to apply it here.

Comment: Perhaps you should rather implement this information in some enums instead of interfaces.

Comment: First of all, I would create a simple `Rectangle` class that encapsulates the four points, that would instantly make your design a lot cleaner.

Comment: The answer is probably a matter of taste but I'd definitely go for something that is backed by a properties file/database/xml file, basically an external source that is not part of the build. It's always a good idea to abstract details out of the code.

Comment: Note that `public static final int[] USERNAME = {1157, 700, 100, 15};` declaration is unsafe. Anybody may do `YourClass.USERNAME[0] = Integer.MIN_VALUE; // mwa-ha-ha!!!` which will silently change the global behavior of your application. In general avoid constant arrays. See also the @biziclop comment.

Comment: I didn't know you could change the value of array elements, I was reading about it, and I will definitely change to Rectangle/Point classes to get that data. I am also reading about factory patterns, as Guillaume pointed out.

Comment: FYI the _Constant Interface_ is an **anti-pattern**. It should not be emulated.

Answer (score 1):

This does not look like constants to me. It seems to be more like configuration. A constant is something that ***never*** changes. In this case, the exact position of components is likely to be modified over time.

You should extract a class similar to :

```
class ComponentPositions {
  Rectangle getUsernamePosition();
  Set<Rectangle> getCommonNumbersPositions();
  [...]
}
```

You can than have multiple instances of this class with different values. Loading the values into this class is another issue that you will have to solve, but you can introduce a Factory (probably called `ComponentPositionConfiguration`) that will be able to load different instances of that config.

Comment: I would opt for a serializable Rectangle class. Easy way to externalize the configuration and clean up the implementation at the same time. Also, you can control mutability in a class a lot more easily.